# MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE не может запустить/остановить сервер

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

В Windows10 MySQL сервер прекрасно стартует и останавливается из cmd с правами админа. Но если делаю server stop или server start из Workbench программа глухо виснет. Пожалуйста подскажите, в чём может быть причина.

Comment: Ну например недостаточно прав... для управления сервисами Workbench тоже следует запускать с правами админа.

Comment: @Akina, к сожалению не помогло.